# Push notification is not working in Lollipop

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

Push notification is not working in lollipop after changing my target SDK to 26, my current minimum SDK is 19. It was working fine before. But after changing to 26, it's now working only in O, N, and M. Please suggest me a solution. Thanks in advance.

Below is my class which extends FirebaseMessaging Service

**FireMsgService.java**

```
 @Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
//        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    Log.e("Msg", "Message received [" + remoteMessage + "]");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1410,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    context = getApplicationContext();
    String message = "";
    String type = "";

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());
        if (jsonObject.has("id"))
            message = (String) jsonObject.get("id");
        if (jsonObject.has("type"))
            type = (String) jsonObject.get("type");
        if (jsonObject.has("room_id"))
            message = (String) jsonObject.get("room_id");
        if (jsonObject.has("type"))
            type = (String) jsonObject.get("type");
        saveTypeId(type,message);
        if (jsonObject.has("badge")) {
            badge = (int) jsonObject.get("badge");
            Log.d("BadgeCount",badge+"");
        }

        Log.e("","------> "+message);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new
            NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
            .setNumber(badge);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_new_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.blue));
    } else {
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setVibrate(new long[0])
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager)
                    getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(1410, notificationBuilder.build());

}
```

Here is my build.gradle file

**build.gradle**

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.abc.xyz"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        multiDexEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since API 26, you have to specify a `ChannelId` to the `Notification.Builder` constructor : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#Notification.Builder(android.content.Context)

More information about Channels : https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

Answer (score 1):

Oreo (API 26) Version since, You must be using NotificationChannel.

if before version used. next code Reference. My Code is

Oreo (API 26) Version since use Channel.

Oreo (API 26) Version before not use Channel.

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                "channel", "channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), mChannel.getId());
    }else {
        notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    }
```

Thank.

Comment: NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH is showing an error